# Derived column expression give truncation error

Tags: ssis, derived-column

I have the following expression: 
`IsNull is column Name`-- all the columns are numeric

ExpectedPremium:

`([Isnull] < ExpectedMinPremium) ? ("Min" + ((DT_WSTR,10)(exp_pct_min * 100)) + "% =  " + (DT_WSTR,10)ExpectedMinPremium) : ([Isnull] > ExpectedMaxPremium) ? ("Max" + ((DT_WSTR,10)(exp_pct_max * 100)) + "% =  " + (DT_WSTR,10)ExpectedMaxPremium) : ""`

The result of the column should look like :  `MAX 60% = 389727.600`

I am not getting an error while creating the derived column but once I run the package I get the following message:

The "Derived Column" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on `"Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[ExpectedPremium]"` specifies failure on truncation.

A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

It writes some rows (less than the input), I increased the destination length and it didn't work.

How to fix this expression?

Comment: You need to increase the length of the output column of the Derived Column transformation.

Comment: @TabAlleman it worked Thank you!